# Работа с куками в curl

Tags: php, curl, cookie

Допустим у меня есть файл с куками, сгенерированный с помощью curl.Как мне в отдельной функции можно обратиться к ссылке, используя эти же куки?Юзерагент и реферер тот же, что и при первом подключении.
Я просто еще не очень понимаю как работает cURL и пытаюсь вот разобраться.

Comment: *не очень понимаю как работает cURL* — как и любой другой http-клиент. включая тот, который сейчас прямо перед вашими глазами.

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас есть файл куков, то при инициализации сессии просто укажите на него ссылку

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'myfile.lst');
```